# How do I load an image from a URL in Silverlight without having the image control be in the visual tree

Tags: c#, silverlight

To load an image from a URL in Silverlight and access its pixel information, you simply create an Image and set the URL as its source and use that image to construct a WriteableBitmap. However, it seems that the Image control must be in the visual tree in order for the image to load. My dilemma is that I am creating an image processing *library* for Silverlight and I will not have access to the visual tree. Is there a way to get around this restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, this seems to work:

```
public void Fetch(Uri uri)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += this.ReadCompleted;
    webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri);
}

private void ReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient webClient = (WebClient)sender;
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted -= this.ReadCompleted;
    Stream stream = e.Result;
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.SetSource(stream);
    WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Comment: Is this still working?
I get a security exception, perhaps related to clientaccesspolicy.xml file.

Comment: @bogdanub, I have the exactly same issue, the Security Exception.  Do you know how to setup the `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't manage to change/edit the clientaccess.xml policy.